# What is the difference between Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices and Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices?

Tags: c#, windows-services

What is the difference between the 2 NuGet packages `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices` and which should be prefered since both seem to provide the same functionality?

Comment: One is for .NET 8.0, and the other is for .NET 6.0 and the .NET Framework

Comment: The "AspNetCore" package (new in .NET 9, not 8) wraps an `IWebHost` in a  `ServiceBase`-derived wrapper. I have no idea why it exists because you can host an ASP.NET Core application as a Windows services without `ServiceBase` using the "Extensions" package. `ServiceBase` is old and inflexible.